# Hive command Line in Horton Sandbox

Tags: hive, putty, hortonworks-sandbox

I have installed Horton sandbox on AWS EC2 instance, and I access the sandbox using putty. How do I access Hive command line?

I tried `hive` but the command not found.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but shell says, command not found

Comment: I see, yes it's installed.

Comment: the result is: no such file or directory

Comment: same result. no such file or directory

Comment: Can you please explain how do you say Hive is installed?

Comment: In the tutorial https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/, after installation of the sandbox, hive is accessible using Ambari/ip address, my understanding was it's available/installed and I just need to start it.

Comment: If you are able to access thru ambari, then it is in running state. The installation path is not set, you need to find out the installation path of hive.

Comment: can you please share  ps -aef|grep  output

Comment: @Roshan,  unfortunately I don't have access to it any more.